# Swing firing listeners during GUI deserialization

Tags: java, swing, serialization, serializable

Today I've encountered a **very nasty bug** that involves firing swing listeners during GUI deserialization using the standard Java serialization API.  It's a bit difficult to concisely explain how to replicate this behavior, so I've posted a small test case below.  This test case does not throw any exceptions, trigger any compiler warnings, and certainly doesn't seem to have a well defined behavior.  **Is this a bug, gray area in Oracle's package interop documentation, or just something that on-one's tried before?**

Just to illuminate my original use-case, I was attempting to automatically update several tabs in an asset-editor upon reloading a configuration component from disk.

```
package com.ihateswing.ssce;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class SSCE implements Serializable {



    private class Internal extends JPanel {
        private final JComboBox<String> m_cb = new JComboBox<String>();

        Internal(final JComboBox<String> cb) {
            cb.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> dcbm = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < cb.getModel().getSize(); ++i) {
                        dcbm.addElement(cb.getModel().getElementAt(i));
                    }
                    m_cb.setModel(dcbm);
                }
            });
            super.add(m_cb);
        }
    }

    private JFrame frame;
    private JComboBox<String> jce = new JComboBox<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SSCE window = new SSCE();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public SSCE() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        stream.defaultReadObject();
        jce.setSelectedIndex(0); // <-- Seems to have undefined behavior?
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jce.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Internal(jce), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(jce, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnAddRandomItem = new JButton("Break");
        btnAddRandomItem.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private int i;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    ((DefaultComboBoxModel<String>) jce.getModel())
                            .addElement(String.valueOf(i++));
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
                    out.writeObject(SSCE.this);
                    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos
                            .toByteArray());
                    ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
                    oin.readObject();

                    // The line below updates 'Internal' as expected, uncomment
                    // to see...
                    // however with the listener fired from the serialization
                    // method, it breaks?
                    // jce.setSelectedIndex(0);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnAddRandomItem, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

}
```

Sample with output (Clicked 'Break' 5 times)

```
package com.ihateswing.ssce;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class SSCE implements Serializable {



    private class Internal extends JPanel {
        private final JComboBox<String> m_cb = new JComboBox<String>();

        Internal(final JComboBox<String> cb) {
            cb.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> dcbm = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < cb.getModel().getSize(); ++i) {
                        dcbm.addElement(cb.getModel().getElementAt(i));
                    }
                    m_cb.setModel(dcbm);
                    System.out.println("Set Internal.m_cb's model with " + m_cb.getModel().getSize() + " elements");
                }
            });
            super.add(m_cb);
        }
    }

    private JFrame frame;
    private JComboBox<String> jce = new JComboBox<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SSCE window = new SSCE();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public SSCE() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        stream.defaultReadObject();
        jce.setSelectedIndex(0); // <-- Seems to have undefined behavior?
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final Internal internal = new Internal(jce);
        jce.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>());
        frame.getContentPane().add(internal, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(jce, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnAddRandomItem = new JButton("Break");
        btnAddRandomItem.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private int i;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    ((DefaultComboBoxModel<String>) jce.getModel())
                            .addElement(String.valueOf(i++));
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
                    out.writeObject(SSCE.this);
                    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos
                            .toByteArray());
                    ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
                    oin.readObject();
                    System.out.println("After returning, Internal.m_cb's model size is " + internal.m_cb.getModel().getSize() + " elements");
                    // The line below updates 'Internal' as expected, uncomment
                    // to see...
                    // however with the listener fired from the serialization
                    // method, it breaks?
                    // jce.setSelectedIndex(0);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnAddRandomItem, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

}

Set Internal.m_cb's model with 1 elements
Set Internal.m_cb's model with 1 elements
After returning, Internal.m_cb's model size is 1 elements
Set Internal.m_cb's model with 2 elements
After returning, Internal.m_cb's model size is 1 elements
Set Internal.m_cb's model with 3 elements
After returning, Internal.m_cb's model size is 1 elements
Set Internal.m_cb's model with 4 elements
After returning, Internal.m_cb's model size is 1 elements
Set Internal.m_cb's model with 5 elements
After returning, Internal.m_cb's model size is 1 elements
```

Comment: How does it *"break"*?

Comment: The combo-box in 'internal' does not update with the model in 'SSCE'...however if you print out the model that is being set, each element of the model is being set within the action listener.  The application is compilable and runnable as is.  Test it out and see.  I will add sample output.  Post is updated.

Comment: I can only speculate that Java's deserialization process overwrites the changes made to the list's model...but it seems unintuitive to me that these changes are occurring after 'defaultReadObject' has been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are updating what you think you are updating.   Here is the same output, if you append to each println m_cb.hashCode().  Note that below, the "Set..." error message indicates that the model is being set on a different instance of m_cb each time.

```
Set Internal.m_cb's model with 1 elements: 44160343
Set Internal.m_cb's model with 1 elements: 1436306574
After returning, Internal.m_cb's model size is 1 elements: 44160343
Set Internal.m_cb's model with 2 elements: 2094948113
After returning, Internal.m_cb's model size is 1 elements: 44160343
Set Internal.m_cb's model with 3 elements: 915510800
After returning, Internal.m_cb's model size is 1 elements: 44160343
Set Internal.m_cb's model with 4 elements: 853795873
After returning, Internal.m_cb's model size is 1 elements: 44160343
Set Internal.m_cb's model with 5 elements: 616759228
After returning, Internal.m_cb's model size is 1 elements: 44160343
Set Internal.m_cb's model with 6 elements: 1385385632
After returning, Internal.m_cb's model size is 1 elements: 44160343
Set Internal.m_cb's model with 7 elements: 1283006722
After returning, Internal.m_cb's model size is 1 elements: 44160343
```

A new instance of m_cb is created in each serialization, and you are setting its model-- but those new combo boxes are not displayed in your frame.

Comment: Seems as though I'll have to re-read the serialization specification.  Thanks.